# ¿como vincular al html el php, para que el formulario de contacto funcione?

Tags: bootstrap, formularios

Un gran saludo.

Tengo este formulario con Bootstrap, sin embargo hay algo de lo cual no estoy segura y es como vincular el .php, al html para que funcione cuando se va ha enviar un correo que salga el mensaje, recibimos tu  solicitud. Lo vincule en el form así , y en el head del html, o no sé si para que se pueda visualizar ya debe ser montado en el servidor.

Gracias.

```css
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
    // 
 
    $email_to = "limnueva@snap.wnkserver8.com";
 
    $email_subject = "Contacto desde Web";
 
    function died($error) {
 
        // mensajes de error
 
        echo "Lo sentimos, hubo un error en sus datos y el formulario no puede ser enviado en este momento. ";
 
        echo "Detalle de los errores.<br /><br />";
 
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
 
        echo "Porfavor corrija estos errores e inténtelo de nuevo.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
 
    // Se valida que los campos del formulairo estén llenos
 
    if(!isset($_POST['nombre']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['telefono']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['solicitud']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
 
        die('Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.');
 
    }
 //En esta parte el valor "name"  sirve para crear las variables que recolectaran la información de cada campo
 
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre']; // requerido
 
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono']; // requerido
 
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // requerido
 
    $solicitud = $_POST['solicitud']; // no requerido 
 
    $message = $_POST['message']; // requerido
 
    $error_message = "";//Linea numero 52;
 
//En esta parte se verifica que la dirección de correo sea válida 
 
   $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
 
    $error_message .= 'La dirección de correo proporcionada no es válida.<br />';
 
  }
 
//En esta parte se validan las cadenas de texto
 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
 
    $error_message .= 'El formato del nombre no es válido<br />';
 
  }
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
 
    $error_message .= 'el formato del apellido no es válido.<br />';
 
  }
 
  if(strlen($message) < 2) {
 
    $error_message .= 'El formato del texto no es válido.<br />';
 
  }
 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
 
    die($error_message);
 
  }
 
//Este es el cuerpo del mensaje tal y como llegará al correo
 
    $email_message = "Contenido del Mensaje.\n\n";
 
 
 
    function clean_string($string) {
 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
 
    }
 
 
 
    $email_message .= "Nombre: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Teléfono: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "solicitud: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Mensaje: ".clean_string($message)."\n";
 
 
//Se crean los encabezados del correo
 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
 
?>
 
 
 
<!-- Mensaje de que fue enviado-->
 
Gracias! Nos pondremos en contacto contigo
 
<?php
 
}
 
?>
```

```html
<!-- Formulario de contacto -->

<div class="formulario">
   <div class="container">
   <h1 class="text-center"><b>CONTACTANOS</b></h1><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
            <form action="js/send_form_email.php">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control input-border" id="email" placeholder="" name="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telefono">Telefóno:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-border" id="pwd" placeholder="" name="pwd">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Correo</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control input-border" id="email" placeholder="" name="email">
              </div>
              
              <label for="solicitud">Tipo de solicitud</label>
              <select class="form-control input-border">
              <option>Cotizar un servicio</option>
              <option>Agendar un servicio</option>
              <option>Unirse al equipo de trabajo</option>
              <option>Otras solicitudes</option>
              </select>

          </form>
          </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <label for="message">Comentario</label>
          <textarea class="form-control input-border" rows="9"></textarea> 
          <br><br>
          <div class="pull-right">
             <div class="form-inline">
                <label for="pwd">Cargar archivo</label>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Seleccionar Archivo</button>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right input-border boton-enviar">ENVIAR</button>
        </div>
      </div>   

  </div>   
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te falta lo principal:

necesitas anidar tus elementos dentro de un form con una etiqueta action:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[Link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)